# How to get the value after the first = in powershell?

Tags: powershell, split

In a file i have

```
datasource =(Description=(failover=on)(load_balance=off) transport_connect_timeout=1)
```

I want to pass the value using `$datasource`.
While I use

```
$datasource =Get-content "c:\file | select-string -pattern datasource"
```

this give me whole line

```
datasource =(Description=(failover=on)(load_balance=off)transport_connect_timeout=1)
```

but I need only

```
(Description=(failover=on)(load_balance=off) transport_connect_timeout=1)
```

please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach:

```
$fullValue = "datasource =(Description=(failover=on)(load_balance=off) transport_connect_timeout=1)"
($fullValue -split "=" | Select-Object -Skip 1) -join "="
```

1. Split the string on the equals signs
2. Grab all but the first split string
3. Join them all back together again using the equals sign

Answer (score 0):

Select-String uses regular expressions with the -Pattern.

I'd use a more advanced one with a [positive look behind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and a [capture group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

```
$datasource = sls .\file.txt -Patt '(?<=datasource =)(.*)$'|% {$_.Matches.groups[1].value}
```

RegEx explanation from [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/y3w3dP/1)

```
(?<=datasource =)(.*)$
 Positive Lookbehind (?<=datasource =)
 Assert that the Regex below matches
 datasource = matches the characters datasource = literally (case sensitive)
1st Capturing Group (.*)
 .*
 . matches any character (except for line terminators)
 * Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, 
   as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
 $ asserts position at the end of a line
```

The pipe to `% {$_.Matches.groups[1].value}` iterates all matches and returns only the content of the capture group [1]